# Что “Undefined offset: 0” и “trying to get property of non-object” уведомления означают?

Tags: php, json, api, вконтакте

Ошибки показываются на линиях 45 и 46. Данный код пример получения списка сообщений (первых 20) с помощью API vk.

[image: Что получается в результате кода]

```
for ($i=0; $i<20; $i++){
    $from_id=$result -> response -> items[$i] -> last_message -> from_id;   
    $users_name = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?v=5.52&access_token=$access_token&user_id=$from_id"));
    $first_name=$users_name -> response[0] -> first_name;  <!--line 45-->
    $last_name=$users_name -> response[0] -> last_name;    <!--line 46-->
    echo $i+1 .") ".$first_name." ".$last_name."<br>";
}
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: на линиях 45 и 45))

Comment: @Alpha ой спасибо)

Answer (score -1):

Ошибка говорит, что в свойстве response нет ключа 0 и так как `response[0]` содержит `null` то оно не может иметь свойство first_name следующая строка такая же.
Вам нужно проверить что содержит `$users_name -> response` например с помощью `var_dump()`.

Comment: а почему тогда она работает в большинстве случаев? Иногда только выводит ошибку. Из 20 сообщений, 8 лагает.

Comment: вы можете сделать `var_dump($from_id)` и посмотреть будет ли значение в каждой итерации

Comment: "  int(-76552532) 6)....................
int(448123661) 7) Riki Yang  "                                                                                                                         Там где не показывает, минусовое значение.